# Setting up method to initialize error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to implement the [ALICE bot](https://github.com/moondroid/ChatBot) in my android app but when I run it on my phone, i'm getting an error saying

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.btbankdemo.bt.btbank/com.btbankdemo.bt.btbank.ChatActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You forgot to call setup method to inizialize BrainLogger

Where am I going wrong?

**My onClick Activity**

```
public class ContactActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

}

public void Chat (View view) {

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

**My MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG_LOG_TAG = "BrainLoggerDialog";

private ListView chatListView;
private static ChatArrayAdapter adapter;
private EditText chatEditText;
private BrainLoggerDialog dialog;
private ResponseReceiver mMessageReceiver;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate savedInstanceState null");
        adapter = new ChatArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext());

        dialog = new BrainLoggerDialog();
        if (!ChatBotApplication.isBrainLoaded()) {
            dialog.show(fm, FRAGMENT_DIALOG_LOG_TAG);
        } else {
            dialog.setPositiveButtonEnabled(true);
        }

    } else {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onCreate savedInstanceState NOT null");
        dialog = (BrainLoggerDialog) fm.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_DIALOG_LOG_TAG);
    }

    chatListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chat_listView);
    chatListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    chatEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat_editText);
    chatEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // Perform action on key press
                final String question = chatEditText.getText().toString();
                adapter.add(new ChatMessage(false, question));
                chatEditText.setText("");

                Intent brainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BrainService.class);
                brainIntent.setAction(BrainService.ACTION_QUESTION);
                brainIntent.putExtra(BrainService.EXTRA_QUESTION, question);
                startService(brainIntent);

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    //hide keyboard
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_BRAIN_STATUS);
    intentFilter.addAction(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_BRAIN_ANSWER);
    intentFilter.addAction(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGGER);

    mMessageReceiver = new ResponseReceiver();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, intentFilter);

    if (dialog != null && ChatBotApplication.isBrainLoaded()) {

        dialog.loadLog();
        dialog.setPositiveButtonEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // Unregister since the activity is not visible
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_log) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        dialog = new BrainLoggerDialog();
        dialog.show(fm, FRAGMENT_DIALOG_LOG_TAG);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


// Broadcast receiver for receiving status updates from the IntentService
private class ResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private ResponseReceiver() {
    }

    // Called when the BroadcastReceiver gets an Intent it's registered to receive
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_BRAIN_STATUS)) {

            int status = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.EXTRA_BRAIN_STATUS, 0);
            switch (status) {

                case Constants.STATUS_BRAIN_LOADING:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "brain loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (dialog != null) {
                        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG_LOG_TAG);
                    }
                    break;

                case Constants.STATUS_BRAIN_LOADED:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "brain loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (dialog != null) {
                        dialog.setPositiveButtonEnabled(true);
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }

        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_BRAIN_ANSWER)) {
            String answer = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_BRAIN_ANSWER);
            adapter.add(new ChatMessage(true, answer));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGGER)) {

            String info = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTENDED_LOGGER_INFO);
            if (info != null) {
                Log.i("EXTENDED_LOGGER_INFO", info);
                if (dialog != null) {
                    dialog.addLine(info);
                }
            }

        }


    }
}


}
```

**BrainLogger.java**

```
public class BrainLogger {

private Context context;
private static BrainLogger instance;
private ArrayList<String> logs;

public static void setup(Context context){
    instance = new BrainLogger(context);
}

public static BrainLogger getInstance(){
    if (instance==null){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You forgot to call setup method to inizialize BrainLogger");
    }
    return instance;
}

private BrainLogger(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    logs = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void info(String line){
    logs.add(line);
    notify(line);
}

public ArrayList<String> getLogs(){
    return logs;
}

private void notify(String line){
    Intent localIntent =
            new Intent(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION_LOGGER)
                    // Puts the status into the Intent
                    .putExtra(Constants.EXTENDED_LOGGER_INFO, line);
    // Broadcasts the Intent to receivers in this app.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
}
}
```

**My Error Log**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>    Process: com.btbankdemo.bt.btbank, PID: 26681
>                                                                             Theme: themes:{default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
>                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.btbankdemo.bt.btbank/com.btbankdemo.bt.btbank.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You forgot to call setup method to inizialize BrainLogger
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: You forgot to call setup method to inizialize BrainLogger
>                                                                                 at com.btbankdemo.bt.btbank.BrainLogger.getInstance(BrainLogger.java:24)
>                                                                                 at com.btbankdemo.bt.btbank.BrainLoggerDialog.loadLog(BrainLoggerDialog.java:139)
>                                                                                 at com.btbankdemo.bt.btbank.BrainLoggerDialog.onCreateDialog(BrainLoggerDialog.java:44)
>                                                                                 at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:407)
>                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
>                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
>                                                                                 at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
>                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
>                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6267)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ContactActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

    <service
        android:name=".LoadBrainService"
        android:exported="false"/>

    <service android:name=".BrainService"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

</application>
```

Comment: It seems as though *"You forgot to call setup method to inizialize BrainLogger"*.

Comment: Basically call `BrainLogger.setup(Context context)` before you call `BrainLogger.getInstance()`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand where I need to call the setup method. :/

Comment: If you want it as a global singleton, you will need to set it up inside an instance of [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html). If you want it to have the same lifecycle as an Activity, call `setup(this)` inside the `onCreate()` method of your activity.

Comment: @DavidRawson, I've already included it inside the Application instance in my AndroidManifest (See update for code) But i'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: No you need to write a subclass of Application. It's not enough to include in the manifest.